# Should I be worried about "Ubuntu experienced internal error on restart" errors?

Tags: apport

Whenever I restart I get an ubuntu experienced internal error asking for details shows the crash is located in usr/bin/xorg.

Should I be worried about this? So far I have not found out what is affected by this crash. It's at the very least annoying so I would like to fix this. If it matters I run on a elitebook 8570w.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been going on for a while?  Occasionally is seems something gets stuck in the apport system and needs to be cleared out.

Open a terminal (press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

In the terminal type the following commands

```
cd /var/crash
sudo rm -r *
exit
```

Please be very sure you are in the /var/crash directory before you execute the 'rm' command.  What we are doing is removing the crash reports from you system - if there is an error still going on, a new crash report will be generated.